# Error when trying to setup Python pip installation behind corporate firewall

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, firewall

I am trying to configure global proxy options for python pip installer so that it works behind corporate firewall.

The command I tried:
`pip config --global set proxy "http://user:pass@host:port"`

The above command gives error with below trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\basecommand.py", line 228, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\configuration.py", line 122, in run
    handlers[action](options, args[1:])
  File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\configuration.py", line 167, in set_name_value
    self.configuration.set_value(key, value)
  File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\configuration.py", line 153, in set_value
    section, name = _disassemble_key(key)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?
Also, I tried creating the `pip.ini` file in %AppData% (windows) as suggested in many posts. Didn't work for me.

Comment: Have you successfully connected to the proxy using the appropriate command-line option? For example, `pip install --proxy=user:pass@server:port numpy`

Comment: I tried this initially but it gave me a problem with certificate. When I tried giving the certificate as well in the same command, it did not work. Now I seem to have broken some other settings and now I am not able to connect at all even after giving the certificate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use section name:

```
pip config --global set global.proxy "http://user:pass@host:port"
```

This sets

```
[global]
proxy = http://user:pass@host:port
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped me configure the required proxy. Still I did not manage to get the connection established though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ubuntu then I think this commad will do..

```
sudo pip --proxy http://web-proxy.mydomain.com install somepackage
```

then exporting the https_proxy environment variable (note its https_proxy not http_proxy):

```
export https_proxy=http://web-proxy.mydomain.com
```

then

```
sudo -E pip install somepackage
```

Comment: I am using Windows system. I tried the windows equivalent of this command but no luck. Tried setting http_proxy, https_proxy variables but did not help. I keep getting connection reset 10054 error.

Answer (score 0):

For windows Try this... use `--proxy http://user:pass@proxyAddress:proxyPort`

If it still having trouble...
Run this command in CMD...

```
set http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyAddress:port

set https_proxy=https://username:password@proxyAddress:port
```

Your pip command..

```
pip install PackageName
```