# Where does pip install get packages from?

Tags: python, installation, pip, repository

Where does pip install get packages from?
In the company I Work the traffic to internet it's going to be blocked but some exceptions can be placed.

I guess pip gets the module packages from different locations, isn't it? Several or just few?
For instance, github I think it's one of those.
Can anyone tell me the most common ones?

(I'm just guessing, I don't really know how it works. If someone can explain.)

Thanks

Comment: Normally pip gets packages from https://pypi.org/  repository.

Comment: Maybe see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51813278/error-when-trying-to-setup-python-pip-installation-behind-corporate-firewall

Answer (score 1):

The pip packages are from https://pypi.org where there are thousands of packages to install.